# Linking 2 graphs for selection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two graphs on a page that shares unique elements (Names of entities) and I want to be able to click on one and it will highlight the element in both graphs. I think this used to be called linking but was removed in recent d3 revisions. Is this still possible somehow?

Comment: Sort of like there SPLOM example? See how they did it? What have you tried? ... can't you give each point a class and then when one is selected in one use jquery (or d3 equiv) to select the other... add a 'selected' class to it?